# How to add springIDE to eclipse 3.3

Tags: eclipse, spring-ide

I am trying to add Spring Framework to my eclipse but as I select download site
there come errors to download spring framework and this is not working.So  I am unable to add Spring framework.

The errors that are come as follows

```
Network connection problems encountered during search.
  Unable to access springide.org/updatesite/site.xml
    Unable to access site: springide.org/updatesite/site.xml [Server returned HTTP response code: "403 Forbidden" for URL: springide.org/updatesite/site.xml.]
    Server returned HTTP response code: "403 Forbidden" for URL: springide.org/updatesite/site.xml.
    Unable to access site: "springide.org/updatesite/site.xml" [Server returned HTTP response code: "403 Forbidden" for URL: springide.org/updatesite/site.xml.]
    Server returned HTTP response code: "403 Forbidden" for URL: springide.org/updatesite/site.xml.
```

Comment: If there is no specific reason to to add SpringIDE to eclipse 3.3, then I would recommend to use Spring Tool Suite (STS) 2.5.2 (it's based on eclipse 3.6)

Answer (score 0):

The messages mean that the update site you are trying to use is not accessible to you.

It appears that the current version of SpringIDE supports Eclipse 3.6 - so you should upgrade - and is to be downloaded from Help->Eclipse Marketplace.